# It is from the freecodecamp and I need help to figure out push() vs concat()

Tags: javascript

Return the lowest index at which a value (second argument) should be inserted into an array (first argument) once it has been sorted. The returned value should be a number.

For example, getIndexToIns([1,2,3,4], 1.5) should return 1 because it is greater than 1 (index 0), but less than 2 (index 1).

Likewise, getIndexToIns([20,3,5], 19) should return 2 because once the array has been sorted it will look like [3,5,20] and 19 is less than 20 (index 2) and greater than 5 (index 1).

```
//This is my code with ".push()" but complier says it is not a function.

function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  return arr.push(num).sort((a,b)=>a-b).indexOf(num)
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([40, 60], 50));


// This is from solution with ".concat".

function getIndexToIns(arr, num) {
  return arr.concat(num).sort((a,b)=>a-b).indexOf(num)
}

console.log(getIndexToIns([40, 60], 50));
```

Why push() doesn't work when concat() does?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Always check your console before asking why things aren't working. Numbers don't have a `sort` function. (`push` does not return the array that was pushed to)

Answer (score 2):

[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) is an array method that accepts some elements to concat, returning *a new array* containing the current elements and the additional ones.  It does not alter either.

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is an array method that updates the content of the current array by adding a new element to the end.  But it simply returns the *length* of the updated array.

Hence

```
arr.push(num)
```

returns the length of the updated array, and you can't call `sort` on it.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you an explanation with example.

The main difference is concat will always returns a new array. But, push will adds an elements to the same array.

For example

```js
 var a=[1,2,3,4], b=4;
 
 a.concat(b) // [1,2,3,4,4]
 
 console.log(a) //[1,2,3,4]
 
 console.log(b) // 4
 
 a.push(b) 
 
 console.log('Push result is::::');
 console.log(a) // [1,2,3,4,4]
 console.log(b) //4
```